# Using JQgrid beforesearch and aftersearch for a loading dialog

Tags: filter, jqgrid, synchronization

I'm using jqgrid with a lot of data and, as the filter is taking too long, I'd like to show a dialog before the search and close it after the search.

The thing that's happening to me, is that when I run the filter in debug mode I see the methods that open and close the dialog get called before the search and after the search, but when I run the filter without interruptions I can't see the dialog, my filter waits 10 seconds or more to refresh the table but the dialog isn't shown.

is it a syncronous problem? or why isn't my dialog showing up?

Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#mytable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
        searchOnEnter : false,
        stringResult : true,
        defaultSearch:'cn', 
        beforeSearch: openDialogLoading, 
        afterSearch: closeDialogLoading
    }
);  


function openDialogLoading(){
    $( "#DialogLoading" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 110,
            width: 50,
            title: 'Loading...',
            modal: true,
            bgiframe: true
    });

    $( "#DialogLoading" ).dialog('open');   
}


function closeDialogLoading(){
    if ($( "#DialogLoading" ).dialog('isOpen')) {
        $( "#DialogLoading" ).dialog('close');
    }    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should include `openDialogLoading` and `closeDialogLoading` which you use. You should verify which zindex have the loading dialog which you try to open. If you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` in the grid then the standard loading dialog will be already shown during reloading the grid.

Comment: Hi, I added the code for the dialogs, the z-index is fine, the dialog works well on other situations, my datatype is 'local' so I don't get the standard loading dialog

Comment: It seems like a memory issue, the browser is so busy doing the search that it can't load the dialog

Comment: is there a wait or something I could use?

Comment: Sorry, but you don't posted enough information. It's unclear which version and which fork of jqGrid you use. It's unclear how many rows you have in jqGrid. It's unclear which web browser you used gor the tests. Do you have the problem only in one grid or you have the same problems in another grids? To be able to hel you really one need to **debug** or to start **profiling** of the demo which reproduce the problem, but one need to have the demo first of all.

Comment: Hi, I'm using jqgrid 4.5.4,by Tony Tomov, Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses, I have 362 rows of data and 13 columns, I'm testing it on chrome, on ie 8, ie 10 and ie 11 it doesn't work on either, this is the only grid where I have tried to do this, because of the time its taking, so I guess it happens on all of them, finally about the demo, I will make a fiddle example and post it. Thanks

Comment: You still don't post full demo. Do you loads the data from the server or locally? I mean, it's important to know whether you sort locally or on the server. It's uncear which formatters you use in the grid. The most important is whether you use local paging or not. I will write you my answer with some demos which would shows the performance of jqGrid loading, sorting and filtering with differnet parameters of the grid. I recommend you don't use so old version of jqGrid and to upgrade to my fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which avalibale unter the same license MIT/GPL2.

Comment: Hi Oleg, sorry for the delay, here is a fiddle with my example https://jsfiddle.net/sw6qkg73/1/, try to change the select from column 2 from mecanic to all, the loading image should show up but, instead you get a time lapse, the real one gets the initial data from the server but the filter is local, I´m going to look at your examples and try your version, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really important to know the details of the grid (options which you use). It's important to use local paging to have good performance with large number of rows. I created some demos for you which you can try and the the time of loading/sorting/filtering:

- [the demo1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-400-20-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 13 columns, 400 rows and the page size 20.
- [the demo2](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-400-400-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 13 columns, 400 rows and the page size 400 (no local paging).
- [the demo3](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 13 columns, 4000 rows and the page size 20.
- [the demo4](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 13 columns, 40000 rows and the page size 20.
- [the demo5](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-1000-1000-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 13 columns, 1000 rows and the page size 1000 (no local paging).

You can see that the performance of the grid depends very havy from the page size. You can play more with differnet values of columns, rows and the page size using the JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1rmmyeLh/ where I used

```
rowNum: 20
```

**UPDATED:** The demo http://jsfiddle.net/1rmmyeLh/7/ which you posted later in the comment some important problems. Modifing the code so that it do displays the "Loading" gif with anymation is realtively easy, see  http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1rmmyeLh/8/.

I included the call of `closeDialogLoading();` inside of `loadComplete` and modified `beforeSearch` so that it returns `true` instead of `false`, which prevent reloading of grid by jqGrid. Additionally I trigger `reloadGrid` inside of `setTimeout` manually:

```js
.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
    beforeSearch: function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        openDialogLoading();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $self.jqGrid("setGridParam", { search: true })
                .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
        }, 0);
        startTime = new Date();
        measureTime = true;
        return true; // SKIP filtering
    }
})
```

Such modification of the code solves the issue with displaying of the "Loading" div. On the other side I stay on my opinion, that the main problem which you have is in ingoring the usage of local paging of data (`rowNum` option).

**I want to stress that it's better, in my opinion, to make the application quickly as to display some "Loading" massage and to hold the application slow**. You use in the demo `rowNum: 4000` with 4000 rows of data. On the other side I can see on my display about 35 rows of data only. If I just change `rowNum` from 4000 to 30 I see the peformance improvement in about 20 times!!! Now you should set clear your priorities. One can speak long about the difficulty for very stupid user to undesrtand the meaning of pager buttons, but in my opinion the difference in performance in 20 times makes any discussions unneeded. Practically every user have used already applications with pagers. So I strictly recommend you to use local data paging. You will be able to work in the style with much more large dataset (see the demo with 40000 rows and the page size 20, which responsibility is more as 3 times better in IE11 as the responsibility of the demo with 400 rows and no paging).

Comment: Hi Oleg, the problem I have is that I need a loading image while filtering, but the before-search event doesn't allow the image to show until it stops, and by then I need to hide the image

Comment: @AnaFranco: I see now what you mean. To fix the problem you can do the following: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1rmmyeLh/8/. I will write some text at the end of my answer to comment the workaround or I will make small changes in the code of free jqGrid. In any way I still think that the **improving performance** is the best solution. The main problem is that JavaScript block the HTML page during filling the page and **willing of 4000 rows, from which one can see only about 30 take a lot of time**. Just try the demo with 40000 rows and the page size 20 and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is what I needed it works great!, I will talk with my PO about the performance but with your help I can modify the grid as she was asking me. :)

Comment: @AnaFranco: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.